# Does the Bootstrap 3 Theme for Drupal meet WCAG 2.0 and ATAG 2.0 standards?

Tags: 7

I'm currently creating a new website for work and I would like our drupal website to be accessible to users with disabilities, and I wanted to know if the Bootstrap 3 Theme meets web accessibility standards like the themes Zen and Adaptive.

I wanted to confirm that the Bootstrap 3 theme is accessible before moving forward with adding content.  I did not find any information on the Bootstrap 3 page on the drupal website specifying the accessibility aspect of the theme.

Comment: Given that [this](http://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/quickref/) is shortened and simplified "quick reference", and it's still damn long, I don't think it is possible to reliably answer your question. Also, you haven't specified how much A you need.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in this bugreport: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/11757 Bootstrap aims to be WCAG compatible. But it does not claim it already is. Also, there are a lot of WCAG guidelines that are not theme-only. The very first one:

> Guideline 1.1 Provide text alternatives for any non-text content so that it can be changed into other forms people need, such as large print, braille, speech, symbols or simpler language.

Obviously, theme cannot force you to comply with it.

## Audit

WCAG is now, effectively, a part of law in European Union. This means that no one will claim to be WCAG compliant lightly, and specialized law / audit companies charge big bucks to give you a "WCAG compatible" document with their signature on it. From my experience, we talk about 4, 5 digits sums, if you need it for government cooperation purposes (like, you want to sell website to a city). Possibly more. Open Source projects hardly have funding for that, that's why you *"did not find any information on the Bootstrap 3 page"*, and you will not in predictable future.

Pay from your own pocket, or use at your own risk.